# Name property in @ManagedBean annotation is not available

Tags: eclipse, jsf, managed-bean

I am trying to make my first JSF application with help of youtube tutorial video. (eclipse/JSF2.0 Dynamic web project). In the first class created, I have to add the below line

```
@ManagedBean (name = "userRegistration")
```

But, when I did the same, eclipse shows an error on "name" keyword and giving suggestion to replace it with "value".

```
@ManagedBean (value = "userRegistration")
```

But it is not working as expected and threw below error.

> /FirstPage.xhtml @10,66 value="#{userRegistration.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'userRegistration' resolved to null

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: @ManagedBean(name="userRegistration") is correct. You can avoid (name="userRegistration") part if your java class is UserRegistration.  Check if you have imported proper class: `java.faces.bean.ManagedBean`

Comment: Have you made the getter and setter functions of name? Please provide the code for your bean

Comment: @anas: what has that to do with the concrete problem?

Comment: @BalusC i had same problem `targetunreachable` ... i later realize i havent created `getter` and `setter` methods of the field after that it worked so i thought maybe this could be the same case over here.

Comment: @anas: the current problem is clearly about the bean instance, not the bean property.

Comment: oops... sorry my mistake

Comment: @VasilLukach thanks.......it worked by adding java.faces.bean.ManagedBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ManagedBean(name="userRegistration")` is correct. You can avoid (name="userRegistration") part if your java class is UserRegistration. Check if you have imported proper class: **java.faces.bean.ManagedBean**

Answer (score 0):

Piggy backing on previous answer, I just had this problem as well. Make sure you have the correct import. There are 2 imports that have the `@ManagedBean` annotation.

`javax.annotation.ManagedBean` & `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`

`javax.annotation.ManagedBean` does not have the attribute name, or eager for that matter.

I noticed that if I just annotated my bean class with @annotation that it would import the `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` class and not the faces one that I wanted.